# why are the spaces in between the words not showing up

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, if-statement, morse-code

I have a morse program but the spaces in between the words are not showing does any one have any ideas? Prefer the simplest way to do so

sample input:

```
APRIL FOOLS DAY
```

output for encode_Morse function:

```
' .-  .--.  .-.  ..  .-..     ..-.  ---  ---  .-..  ...     -..  .-  -.-- '
```

output for the decode_Morse function:

```
APRILFOOLSDAY

MORSE_CODES={'A':' .- ','B':' -... ','C':' -.-. ',
'D':' -.. ','E':' . ','F':' ..-. ','G':' --. ',
'H':' .... ','I':' .. ','J':' .--- ','K':' -.- ',
'L':' .-.. ','M':' -- ','N':' -. ','O':' --- ',
'P':' .--. ','Q':' --.- ','R':' .-. ',
'S':' ... ','T':' - ','U':' ..- ','V':' ...- ',
'W':' .-- ','X':' -..- ','Y':' -.-- ','Z':' --.. '}

##Define functions here
def encode_Morse(my_msg):
  #my_msg=my_msg.upper()

  my_msg_Morse=""
  for letter in my_msg:
    
    if letter!=" " and letter not in MORSE_CODES:
      my_msg_Morse+="*"
    elif letter!=" ":
       my_msg_Morse+= MORSE_CODES[letter]
    else:
      my_msg_Morse+="   "

  return my_msg_Morse+""


def decode_Morse(my_msg): 
 
  string=""
  
  for word in my_msg.split("     "):
  
    for ch in word.split():
      if ch!="  " and ch!="*":
        string=string + list(MORSE_CODES.keys())[list(MORSE_CODES.values()).index(" "+ch+" ")]
      elif ch=="     ":
        string+=" "
    string=string+"" 

  return string
```

Comment: i need it because I need a two spaces between morse characters

Comment: It would be way simpler if your mapping `MORSE_CODES` didn't use spaces at all and you would handle them outside the conversion.

Comment: @ExplooreX that makes no sense, I need four spaces between words and I am telling you I need two spaces after each character

Comment: @qwvst sorry for that please update `string=string+""` to `string=string+" "`

Comment: Why do you need that two spaces?

Comment: @ExplooreX that just adds another space at the end, i dont need that

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo, that is not a question to ask... i just want to format like that

Comment: @qwvst define another condition that check for last condition of main loop in decoded function

Comment: @ExplooreX like what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split function absorbes your delimiter

I propose :

```
def decode_Morse(my_msg): 
 
  words = [] 
  
  for word in my_msg.split("     "):
    string = ""
    for ch in word.split():
      string=string + list(MORSE_CODES.keys())[list(MORSE_CODES.values()).index(" "+ch+" ")]
    words.append(string)

  return " ".join(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

I propse you this solution:

```
MORSE_CODES={
    'A':'.-','B':'-...','C':'-.-.',
    'D':'-..','E':'.','F':'..-.','G':'--.',
    'H':'....','I':'..','J':'.---','K':'-.-',
    'L':'.-..','M':'--','N':'-.','O':'---',
    'P':'.--.','Q':'--.-','R':'.-.',
    'S':'...','T':'-','U':'..-','V':'...-',
    'W':'.--','X':'-..-','Y':'-.--','Z':'--..'
}

R_MORSE_CODES = {v:k for k,v in MORSE_CODES.items()}

def encode_morse(msg):
    words = msg.split()
    
    return "  ".join(" ".join(MORSE_CODES.get(c, '*') for c in w) for w in words)
    
def decode_morse(msg):
    words = msg.split("  ")
    return " ".join("".join(R_MORSE_CODES.get(c, '?') for c in w.split()) for w in words)

# Original message
msg = "APRIL FOOLS DAY"

enc_msg = encode_morse(msg)
print(enc_msg)
# .- .--. .-. .. .-..  ..-. --- --- .-.. ...  -.. .- -.--

dec_msg = decode_morse(enc_msg)
print(dec_msg)
# APRIL FOOLS DAY
```

Deviating from your solution, I

1. do not use spaces in the translation table between characters and morse codes.
2. use one space character to seperate single morse codes and two space to mark word separation

For back translation i reverse the dictionary keys and values to another translation table called `R_MORSE_CODES` for better readability.

Using one and two spaces is sufficient to allow compatibility to decode a morse code back to its original message, as long as any unknown characters appear.